# MySQL/PHP insert new value into a table (if its not already there) and get its PK either way

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I have a table named WORDS where there is just a primary key (ID), and a column WORD.  The WORD column should be unique varchar, and the ID is an auto-incrementing integer field.

In SQL Terms,

```
CREATE TABLE WORDS(
    ID INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    WORD VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE(WORD)
);
```

While going through a list of words in PHP, I'd like to insert a new word to the WORDS table.  If it's already present, I'd like nothing to happen - and if it isn't present I'd like it to be inserted.

I found the best solution to this was using `INSERT IGNORE`.  I have to go one step further now though... my PHP script needs to know the primary key of the word after its inserted into the table.  If it wasn't already present, this is easy - I can just use `mysql_insert_id`.  If it was present though, I seem to have to do a query on the table to get what the primary key for that word already was.

Is there a neat way to do:

> "Insert this into the table if it's not already there, and give me the
>   primary key it's in either way."

by any chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this. But you can cut it down to a function

```
function wordDB($word) {
  $sql = "select * from WORDS where WORD = '".$word."'";
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
  if($result) { #if exists
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      $id = $row['id'];
    }
  } else { # if doesn't exist
    $insertSQL = "insert into WORDS (WORD) values ('".$word."')";
    mysql_query($insertSQL);
    $id = mysql_insert_id();
  }
  return $id;
}
```

This is a short function to do everything that you basically asked.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
INSERT INTO WORDS(`WORD`) VALUES ('word')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ID = LAST_INSERT_ID(ID)
```

And then check `mysql_insert_id`. It should return either inserted or old id (at least mysql `LAST_INSERT_ID()` works this way.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I wouldn't bother to find a "neat" way.
Sometines such a search will be just a waste of time and sometimes the "neat" solution turns an ugly one.

What for do you need your words? Why not to select it first (as select is way cheaper than insert) and then insert only if it's not present?